# Get title for list in csr file attached via jslink?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jslink, client-side-rendering

I need to get the list name (or title) the user is currently viewing to complete a url. I'm good with ctx.Currentitem references but no idea how to get list data like "title". 
Need something like this replacing list header (obviously *not* ctx.ListTitle):

```
 overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<a  
 href='/site/Lists/" + ctx.ListTitle 
 + "/Calendar.aspx?IsDlg=1'>Access 
 full calendar</a>";
```

UPDATE:
Since the web part already has a link to the list's default view in the title url property, it was easier to reposition that than monkey with the csr file.

Comment: `_spPageContextInfo.listTitle` would work on the list view, not on a webpart.

Answer (score 0):

In JSLink, the List Title can be got

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  Templates: {
       Header:"Hello world from <#= ctx.ListTitle #>!"
  }
});
```

[image]